# Obtener ID de los option de un select con JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto PHP y uso el framework Laravel 5.4, y quiero obtener el id seleccionado de un `select`.

Y así es como tengo mi `select` y como es que lo lleno con los datos:

```
<select name="location_id" id="addLocationIdReq" onchange="ShowSelected();">
    <option value="" disabled selected >Seleccione un inventario:</option>
    <option value="">Otro</option>
    @foreach($locations as $location)
        <option value="{{$location->id}}">{{$location->name}}
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Bien y es así como muestra los diferentes campos que tengo en mi base de datos, pero quiero saber cómo obtener el id de los `option`, y guardarlo en una variable y quiero mostrarlo en un `alert` (esto es solo a modo de prueba).

Intenté hacerlo con JavaScript, pero no resultó:

```
function ShowSelected()
{
    var cod = document.getElementById("location_id").value;
    alert(cod);
}
```

Y es que quiero obtener ese id, para hacer una especie de validación:
Depende que locación se haya seleccionado , así es como mostrara los inventarios que están asociados a esta locación, y es por eso que necesito obtener el `id` de la locación.

Comment: El id `location_id`  que intenta seleccionar no es correcto _(a menos que tenga otro select con ese id)_ , el id del select es `addLocationIdReq ` debería funcionar con  `var cod = document.getElementById("addLocationIdReq").value;`

Comment: Muchas Gracias Dev. la verdad es que estoy aprendiendo a usar Javascript, con tu comentario, ya aparece el alert

Answer (score 3):

Dentro de tu archivo JS que referencias a tu página, con JQUERY y menor líneas de código puedes obtener el ID de la opción que seleccionas de tu SELECT con esta 2 líneas de código

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var id = $('#addLocationIdReq').val();    //#addLocationIdReq es el identificador
                                          // de tu elemento
alert(id);
});
```

Y con eso te debería de desplegar el ID de la opción seleccionada.

Answer (score 1):

Tu select tiene el id **addLocationIdReq**

Por lo que tu JS podría ser algo así:

```
var select = document.getElementById("addLocationIdReq"); /*Obtener el SELECT */
var valor = select.options[select .selectedIndex].value; /* Obtener el valor */
```

Comment: Accediendo a `value`  ya obtendremos el `value` del `option` seleccionado. no es necesario todo el proceso que realizó.

Comment: Es un buen dato, muchas gracias por comentarla.